# Cleaning up private clipboard formats

Tags: windows, clipboard

When an application puts data on the clipboard in a private format (`CF_PRIVATEFIRST` to `CF_PRIVATELAST`) then it has to free it in response to `WM_DESTROYCLIPBOARD`, because for these formats the system won't do it automatically.

1. It ought logically to be true that a private format used by one application won't be seen by any other application (even if they use the same format code in the private range).

   a) How does the system enforce this? Does it use the clipboard owner (window handle)?

   b) Do private format items automatically get removed from the clipboard when the owner window is closed? (Using a clipboard viewer it seems that they do not.) So what happens when window handles are reused?
2. In addition to freeing the memory in response to `WM_DESTROYCLIPBOARD`, do you also need to free it when the application exits? (I know that the clipboard uses global memory so that the data can be accessed from any process, so I'm guessing it isn't automatically freed when the process that created it exits.)
3. Ideally, you would remove just the private formats and leave any standard formats in place when the application exits, but I can't find an API call to remove just one format from the clipboard. Is there a simple way to do this other than emptying the clipboard and then explicitly writing back to it the non-private formats?

I've searched the MSDN documentation and Google and can't find answers to these questions, so can anyone here help?

(I know about registered clipboard formats. I'm not asking about those.)

Comment: Are you sure about one application not seeing the other's clipboard format if they use the same name? I can drag & drop between 2 instances of the same application using a private format. Don't see a reason why this shouldn't be true for 2 different applications.

Comment: @user2543253 I assume you meant 'if they use the same _number_ '; private clipboard formats don't have names. The problem is that if private clipboard format numbers were shared between all applications then there would have to be some central register of private formats to prevent two applications using the same number for different things. And then they are no longer private formats but public, documented formats like CF_TEXT. Are you confusing them with registered clipboard formats?

Comment: I meant the same name when registering with "RegisterClipboardFormat". Because then they get the same number. Re-reading the docs, I find: " This enables more than one application to copy and paste data using the same registered clipboard format". What do you mean "confusing with registered formats"? Aren't clipboard formats I register myself private formats?

Comment: Ah, I see. "An application can use a private clipboard format for an application-defined data format that does not need to be registered with the system." Thanks for kind of pointing me there.

Answer (score 0):

Non-authoritative answer, but it may guide your testing to determine the truth:

1. I think contrary to the documentation for [SetClipboardData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649051(v=vs.85).aspx) when using a private format the ownership of the memory of the passed handle is not given to the system. Thus any other program trying to read the clipboard would be getting the handle for data it couldn't read. Test: can your clipboard viewer actually retrieve the private data, or just the handles?
2. I believe the memory that you are supposed to free is your own application memory that you referenced when you called SetClipboardData. So you don't need to free the memory on application exit as it should be freed with the rest of your memory.
3. The private formats would point to data that no longer existed, similar to delayed rendering data that was not rendered when the WM_RENDERALLFORMATS message was received.